# Multiple tests with multiple throws

Tags: java, testing, throw

I would like to create a method that will test different things and **throw an error depending on the issue** (and then exit the program).
I am not really familiar with throwing exception... Is this method a good way to program it?

```
private static void testConnexions() throws IOException, Exception {

    File file = null;
    Socket socket;

    try {
        // Test access to the repository:
        file = new File(pdfRepository);
        if (!file.canRead())
            throw new SecurityException();
        if (!file.canWrite())
            throw new SecurityException();
        if (!file.exists())
            throw new SecurityException();
        if (!file.isDirectory())
            throw new SecurityException();

        // Connection to  Filenet:      
        connexion = new FilenetConnexion(filenetURI, objectStoreName,
                stanza, dossierRacine, userName, password);
        connexion.connect();

        // Connection to a socket:
        socket = new Socket(serveurCV, portCV);

        // Initialize the JavaMail Session:
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        if (serveurSMTP != null)
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", serveurSMTP);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
}
```

I would like to catch a message detailed enough to know if the repository can't be written in, or if the System.getProperties() got an error, etc.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**
Here is the solution I chose among all your contributions, hoping it can help someone:

```
private static void testConnexions() {

        File file = null;
        Socket socket;

        // Test access to the repository:
        try {
            file = new File(pdfRepository);
            if (!file.canRead())
                throw new SecurityException(pdfRepository + " can't be read.");
            if (!file.canWrite())
                throw new SecurityException(pdfRepository + " can't be written.");
            if (!file.exists())
                throw new SecurityException(pdfRepository + " doesn't exist.");
            if (!file.isDirectory())
                throw new SecurityException(pdfRepository + " isn't a folder.");    
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Connection to  FileNet       
        try {
            connexion = new FilenetConnexion(filenetURI, objectStoreName,
                    stanza, dossierRacine, userName, password);
            connexion.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Impossible to connect to FileNet. " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(2);
        }

        // Connection to FrontalSocket
        try {
            socket = new Socket(serveurCV, portCV);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            logger.error("Impossible to connect to FrontalSocket. " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Impossible to connect to FrontalSocket. " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(3);
        }

        // Initialize the JavaMail session
        try {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            if (serveurSMTP != null)
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", serveurSMTP);
            else{
                logger.error("The SMTP host name is null");
                System.exit(4);
            }
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Impossible to connect to SMTP server. " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(4);
        }
    }
```

Comment: NO! All of the SecurityException that you throw are going to get caught in the empty catch-all `catch Exception` block.

Comment: Oops yes sorry, forgot to complete it.

Comment: Since you mentioned that you are not familiar with throwing exceptions, please stop now and read an introductory level Java book. You will learn how to use exceptions and many other things.

Comment: BTW, since you already catch `Exception` and `IOException` in your code, your method will never throw them. This means you can remove the `throws IOException, Exception` clause from your method. That is only for exceptions that you do not want to catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this several ways, choose which one fits your scenario best:

- Throw different exceptions based on each error scenario. It is easy to subclass `Exception` and create the distinction this way.
- Throw the same exception with a specific error message depending on the error scenario.

An example of case 1:

First define your own exceptions:

```
public class CannotReadException extends Exception {
   // This is a separate class in your project
}
public class CannotWriteException extends Exception {
   // This is a separate class in your project
}
```

Then throw and catch them:

```
try {
        // Test access to the repository:
        file = new File(pdfRepository);
        if (!file.canRead())
            throw new CannotReadException();
        if (!file.canWrite())
            throw new CannotWriteException();
        ...
} catch (CannotReadException e) {
   // Do stuff for the specific error
} catch (CannotWriteException e) {
   // Do stuff for the specific error
}
```

or, case 2:

```
try {
        // Test access to the repository:
        file = new File(pdfRepository);
        if (!file.canRead())
            throw new SecurityException( "cannot read" );
        if (!file.canWrite())
            throw new SecurityException( "cannot write" );
        ...
} catch (SecurityException e) {
   // Get to your specific message using e.getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest in this case to throw a user define exception and pass a message detailed enough to know the responsible for that error.

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    //override the needed methods.
}
```

then throw you own defined exception with a detaied message.

```
try {
    // Test access to the repository:
    file = new File(pdfRepository);
    if (!file.canRead())
        throw new MyException("The fine has no read permission");
```